# Is the Grammar wrong

Tags: grammar, verbs, ing, present-progressive, foreign-phrases

I am foreigner. This is my first time to create article.
If I get some mistake.
I hope you will excuse and teach me.
The article is written in stackoverflows.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521848/how-to-show-tooltip-image-when-hover-on-button-pyqt5/60522104#60522104

But the grammar in textbook in Taiwan. After the  word  "when" will connect V-ing (present progressive).

Hover in the article is after "when". So the word hover will become hovering.

Is the article grammar wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please paste the sentence you are speaking about in the body of the question.